# ng-repeat with a custom read-more directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I have an ng-repeat, `ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index"`, then a 'p' tag with a custom directive that will limit the amount of words in the post until the user clicks 'read more'.

`<p read-more>{{post.thePost}}</p>`

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.

It will work when I have plain text in between the 'p' tags, but when I have multiple items from `$scope.posts`, I think it is failing to read the actual text.

Any way to get around this?

Here is the read-more angular directive I am using:

https://github.com/pattysnippets/angular-readmore

Comment: Have you tried using the `content` attribute as specified in the docs? e.g. `<p read-more content="{{post.thePost}}"></p>`.

Comment: @GregL I tried that too, still the same issue.

Comment: From the looks of the directive, the issue may be that the link function is attempting to execute before the actual content is loaded.

Would <p read-more ng-if="post">{{post.thePost}}</p> help, or some other way of only adding the read-more paragraph to the DOM once there is content to execute on?

Answer (score 2):

The key does seem to be using the `content` attribute.

Here is the key markup:

```
<p ng-show="loading">Loading posts...</p>
<p ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index" read-more content="{{post.text}}"></p>
```

And here is my controller code that simulates loading in posts from the server:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.loading = true;
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.posts = [1, 2, 3].map(function(id) {
      return {
        id: id,
        heading: 'Post ' + id,
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor (...etc...)'
      };
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

Here is [the Plunkr with it working](http://plnkr.co/edit/pBgEvxLr2BruCV0cKmOv?p=preview).